# libtiff4:i386 is not available

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

The package: "libtiff4" is now unavailable.

So, for people who have problem trying to install `libtiff4:i386`

And came out with this output:

```
zorin@Samsung-NP300E4Z-S03TH:~$ sudo apt-get install libtiff4:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff4:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff4:i386' has no installation candidate
zorin@Samsung-NP300E4Z-S03TH:~$
```

The answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:** this is only for users that have releases higher than 14.04

1.Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).

2.Type in:

- `sudo su`
- `echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list`
- `apt-get update`

Then install the package with:`apt-get install libtiff4`.

After that you won't need the saucy updates anymore. Disable it with:

- `mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list.backup`
- `apt-get update`
- `exit`

That all!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: E: The repository 'http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.